# python for loop result in ffmpeg command

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, video-streaming

hi im trying to insert for loop results in a ffmpeg command i tried some code but all i get is first text with no sound and it glitches and freezes i tried many modification but no success i appreciate if you have any ideas that would be great, the imported text from api should display only the duration of audio file here is my code:

```py
import requests
import json
import os
import requests
import http.client
import io
import subprocess


response = requests.get('http://api.quran.com:3000/api/v3/chapters/2/verses?text_type=image&language=ar&recitation=10')

json = json.loads(response.content)

data= json['verses']
#print(data)

for i in data:
    input_text = i['text_madani'] 
    input_duration = i['audio']['duration'] 
    input_mp3 = i['audio']['url']
    input_img = i['image']['url']
 #   print(input_duration)
    command = f'''ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 \
                    -i img2.jpeg \
                    -i {input_mp3} \
                    -vf 'pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2,drawtext=enable='between(t, n, {input_duration})':text={input_text}:fontsize=90:x=50:y=50:fontcolor=black@0.8' \
                    -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k \
                    -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 \
                    -c:a aac -b:a 160k \
                    -ac 2 -ar 44100 \
                    -y -f flv rtmp://localhost/hls/test''' 
    print(command)
    os.system(command)
```

Comment: First you should determine if problem is from the python code or the ffmpeg command. Get the ffmpeg command working before you put it in python. If it no longer works then you know the problem is with the python code.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i already tested the ```python``` code with api only without ```ffmpeg``` command it is working ahd i can fetch element from ```api json```and ```ffmpeg``` command is also working